# Bounds on Gaussian infinite sum

Tags: summation, numerical-methods, approximation, gaussian-integral

What are some good upper and lower bounds on the following sum?

$$S=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n}{\sigma}\right)^2}$$

I am looking for something better than $1<S<2$.

Comment: The trivial bound $S>1/\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}$ holds (so $S<2$ is wrong).

Comment: For large $\sigma$, the summation gets close to the integral, so $S\approx 1$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for the correction. I meant $1<S<1+\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lower bound is $S(\sigma) \gt \max\left\{1, \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}  \right\}$, based on the integral and the $n=0$ term. For large and small $\sigma$, the result is close to this lower bound.

An upper bound is the lower bound multiplied by $S\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}\right) \approx S(0.3989423) \approx 1.086435$ with equality when $\sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$.

Answer (score 3):

If fact, there is an explicit solution to the expression
$$S=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n}{\sigma}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2 \pi }  }\,\vartheta _3\left(0,e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma ^2}}\right)$$ where appears the elliptic theta function.

The function decreases asymptotically to $1$ but it goes to infinity for small values of $\sigma$.

I give you below some values (if you need more, just ask me)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\sigma & S \\
 0.10 & 3.98942 \\
 0.15 & 2.65962 \\
 0.20 & 1.99473 \\
 0.25 & 1.59684 \\
 0.30 & 1.34009 \\
 0.35 & 1.17832 \\
 0.40 & 1.08500 \\
 0.45 & 1.03673 \\
 0.50 & 1.01438
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

Using $x=e^{-\frac{1}{2 \sigma ^2}}$, we can expand (around $x=0$) $$\vartheta _3\left(0,x\right)=1+2\sum_{i=1}^\infty x^{n^2}$$ which will converge very fast since $x<1$. For any value of $\sigma$, the function approximation will be extremely accurate with very few terms.

Comment: So then what are some good upper and lower bounds for $\vartheta_3 (0,e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}})$?  I'm looking for an approximation that is efficient to compute.

Comment: For what range of $\sigma$ ?

Comment: There's no general formula?

Comment: I asked you for what range of $\sigma$. The next question is : do you want an approximate way to compute its value ? I don't see hoaw to bound this.

Comment: How about arbitrary range? I do want to compute its value approximately.  Also, what is the definition of $\vartheta_3$?

Comment: Jacobi theta function. If you tell me more about the contexr, I could think about an approximation. Which kind of accuracy ?

Comment: I'm summing together $2N+1$ signals of relative amplitudes $e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-N}{\sigma}\right)^2},\ldots1,\ldots e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{N}{\sigma}\right)^2}$ and I want to choose a $C(\sigma)$ factor so that the sum of the amplitudes is approximately constant as $\sigma$ changes.  I don't want it to clip, but I don't want it to be too quiet either.

Comment: "For any value of $\sigma$": you'll need $n>k\sigma$ anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}$. This is an even function, so that all its derivatives of odd order are odd; they vanish at zero and infinity.

Using the Euler-McLaurin summation formula,

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty f(k)=\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx+B_1(f(\infty)-f(0))+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!}\left(f^{(2k-1)}(\infty)-f^{(2k-1)}(0)\right)\\
=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}\sigma-\frac12.$$

I can't believe my eyes, what's wrong ?

Comment: I think $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2k}}{(2k)!} f^{(2k-1)}(x)$ doesn't converge to $0$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$ because its terms aren't uniformly convergent.

Comment: Also, not to be nitpicky, but you should have $\sigma\sqrt{2\pi} - \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers: the integral is one-sided.

Comment: Oh never mind then.

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers: the derivatives are Hermite polynomials times the Gaussian so they do decrease quickly for large $x$ :( From what I see, the E-McL coefficients decrease like $(1/2\pi)^{2k}$, while the derivatives follow $x^{2k-1}e^{-x^2/2}$.

Comment: Then they don't converge uniformly.  For all $N\geq 0 $, you can choose $k$ large enough that $\frac{x^{2k-1}e^{-x^2/2}}{(2\pi)^k}\geq 1$ for some $x\geq N$.

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers: I am amazed that this is enough to erase all terms of the series, which gives no approximation at all.

Comment: What are you referring to by "this"?

Comment: @JoshuaMeyers: non-uniform convergence. I would have expected meaningless/non-converging terms rather than all zeroes.